# Cannot send mail using PEAR Mail for port 587 but yes for port 25

Tags: php, smtp

I cannot seem to get `port 587` to send mail. I am capable of sending mail using `port 25`. I'm using PEAR Mail to send this.

```
require_once "Mail.php";

/**************************************************
EDIT the following variables for your own use
***************************************************/
$from = "Noreply <noreply@host.com>";
$to = "Abc <abc@host.com>";

$subject = "Hi!"; //type in subject here

$host = "mail.host.com"; // also tried ssl://mail.host.com and tls://mail.host.com
$username = "noreply@host.com"; // Your user / full email address
$password = "password"; // Password to your email address

/**************************************************
***************************************************/

$body = "test message";
$headers = array (
'From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
'auth' => true,
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password,
'port'=>587));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

Comment: Is there a PEAR error you can check?

Comment: @phansen array(2) { [0]=> int(530) [1]=> string(41) "5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first" }

Comment: Is it the same error when using ssl://mail.host.com ?

Comment: @phansen array(2) { [0]=> int(-1) [1]=> string(0) "" } for `var_dump($smtp->getSMTPObject()->getResponse());`

Comment: @phansen so its a return code of -1 for ssl://

Comment: Sorry I can't be much help as I've never had that problem when using PEAR Mail.  At least you know that it doesn't like the auth connection and you can keep searching for solutions related to that.  Make sure you double-check that the mail server itself is working as expected on that port, before you keep trouble shooting the php code.

Answer (score 0):

Enable SMTP TLS / SSL in PEAR::MAIL

Edit the file - /pear/Net_SMTP/Net/SMTP.php

Find the line with the following content (approximately line 590):

function auth($uid, $pwd, $method = '', $tls = false, $authz = '')

Replace this with:

function auth($uid, $pwd, $method = '', $tls = true, $authz = '')

So your changing '$tls' from 'false' to 'true'
Save the file
And try with port 587